# Taylor series identity for polynomial using Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The following question is from Kirillov's Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, and my attempt is the following:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(t\partial_x)^n}{n!}f=(\exp{t\partial_x})f=\exp(\rho(t))f=\rho(\exp(t))f$$
The last identity comes from the fact that $\exp\circ\rho_*=\rho\circ\exp$, where $\rho_*$ is an induced morphism of $\rho$. (The author used the same symbol $\rho$ for both of these morphisms.) 
But the last expression seems to have no connection with what I want to show, which is $f(x+t)$. What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: **Hint** Compute explicitly $\exp (t\partial_x)$.

Comment: Sorry, but could you give me a hint for that hint?

Comment: If we let $L_a$ denote left multiplication (so, $x \mapsto x + a$), we see that the pushforward $T_x L_a \cdot \partial x$ of $\partial x$ by $L_a$ is just $\partial_x$ (say, by using the obvious curve, $s \mapsto x + s$). So, the left-invariant vector field corresponding to $(\partial_x)_0 \in T_0 \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$ is $\partial_x$, and by linearity the one corresponding to $t (\partial_x)_0$ is $t \partial_x$. This has the obvious integral curve $s \mapsto s t$, and so $\exp (t(\partial_x)_0) = s t\vert_{s = 1} = t$.

Comment: That completely makes sense!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found it helpful! (Of course, both instances of $\partial x$ are supposed to be $\partial_x$.)